# Is research percent needed at max?

Tags: civilization-4

I am in a game where I have maxed out all that I can research. It's already up to future tech 16, and I was basically wondering if I could drop my percentage on research to 0% once I get to future tech, and focus all my attention (budget wise) on the culture instead?  Will this have any negative impact on my game?

Comment: Or, in Beyond the Sword, on [Espionage](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Espionage_(Civ4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no downside to dropping your science to 0 aside from the obvious- you won't ever research anything. Since Future Tech is pretty lousy (especially once you've got to that level), there really is no reason to keep researching.

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted solution is correct, it is worth noting that the sliders are based on your commerce so wont change the beakers (science) produced from specialists.

If you plan to have all your beakers produced from scientists and specialists (considered a specialist economy) then the slider percent won't change the specialist research.

If you go this way you can run your science slider at zero and still be getting decent research.